# How to get specific fields like gender or email of a user through Graph API

Tags: swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api, swift4

I have this code:

```
import FacebookCore

    let connection = GraphRequestConnection()
    connection.add(GraphRequest(graphPath: "/me")) { httpResponse, result in
      switch result {
      case .success(let response):
        print("Graph Request Succeeded: \(response)")
      case .failed(let error):
        print("Graph Request Failed: \(error)")
      }
    }
    connection.start()
```

Which is executed after successful login. Now what I get, are just basic information, like name, or id.

Still, I need gender and email...So I tried this:

```
let params = ["fields": "id, name, gender, email"]
```

then:

```
 connection.add(GraphRequest(graphPath: "/me", parameters: params)) { httpResponse, result in
```

Still, I get the same data, only `id` and `name` in the response.

Comment: The user need to have granted you user_gender and email permissions for you to get those fields

Comment: @WizKid Can you be more specific? How can I do that?

Comment: By asking them for those permissions during login …?

Comment: @misorude After login

Comment: You can not ask for permissions _after_ login, asking for permissions is _part of_ the login flow. (If you did initially ask for less permission than you need, then you need to send the user through the login flow again.)

Comment: @misorude Hm, I will check that out. Actually not in front of a code, so I can't actually say the real state. But I think I did it after login :(

Comment: Nah, I was doing it actually before actual login. So that part is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go through this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.2/user) to find out user what information is available for you through API.

Other than this you need to ensure that your Facebook App has the right **permissions** and that they are approved by Facebook. Below screenshot shows approved permissions in Facebook's Developer App Dashboard under the **App Review** Tab in which you can see email, which is required if you need the users email.

[image: Approved Permission screenshot]

You can visit this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/) to find out the steps to get permissions approved for your Facebook App

Comment: Hey thhanks! Ok, but how do I set gender in approved items? I don't see it there.

Comment: Go to [https://developers.facebook.com/apps/<YOUR_APP_ID>/review-status/](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/<YOUR_APP_ID>/review-status/).
Click on ***Add Items*** button.
A popup will appear in that if you scroll down a little you will be able to see ***user_gender*** permission